# Angular method executes indefinitely when it uses with the ng-style

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

**HTML**

```
<div class="progress-bar" ng-style="{width: Event.Methods.GetProgress() + '%'}"></div>
```

**JS**

```
 GetProgress: function () {
                    var total = Number($scope.Event.Item.Total);
                    var goal = Number($scope.Event.Item.Goal);
                    if (total > goal) {
                        total = goal;
                    }
                    return Math.round((total / goal) * 100);
                },
```

I have used above code to show a progress bar on the page.Progress bar is working fine.But when I put a debug point on the `GetProgress()` method where it executes indefinitely.When I remove the `ng-style` then there is no problem (But you know then my progress bar is also not working).So could you tell me how to avoid above kind of behaviour ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you make example on http://plnkr.co

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML

```
<div class="progress-bar" ng-style="{width: progressValue + '%'}"></div>
```

JS

```
//initially setup the value
$scope.progressValue = 0;

//then on every call of GetProgress is updated 
 GetProgress: function () {
                    var total = Number($scope.Event.Item.Total);
                    var goal = Number($scope.Event.Item.Goal);
                    if (total > goal) {
                        total = goal;
                    }
                    $scope.progressValue = Math.round((total / goal) * 100);
                },
```

Comment: Could you explain why this is happening (I mean indefinite execute)?